# Django: How to order comments of a post directly under each original post object?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I’m creating a django app that allows posting something on each user’s page and then allowing people to comment on each of those posts. I’m trying to get the associated comments for each post and display them right under each post in timestamp order. I have figured out how to do this for the original posts of each profile using allpageposts = username.newpost_set.all().order_by('-postdate'), but can’t seem to figure out what the best way to do it for comments even though it seems at first it’d be the same type of logic as the original posts. The problem I am having is that I need to keep track of which comments are for which specific ‘newpost’ in a user’s page which can have many ‘newposts’ on their page. What is a good way that I can capture each page's newpost's comments and display them in a template? Thanks for any tips or hints. Here are my models:

```
class newpost(models.Model):
    newlinktag = models.ForeignKey('username') 
    postcontent = models.CharField(max_length=1024) 
    postdate = models.DateTimeField()
    postlikes = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)  
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.postcontent

class postcomment(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=False) 
    commenttag = models.ForeignKey('newpost')
    postcommentdate = models.DateTimeField() 
    commentlikes = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.comment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understand you correct, you need something like this:

```
for post in username.newpost_set.all():
    comments = postcomment.objects.filter(commenttag=post).order_by('-postcommentdate')
    # your code here
```

Comment: wouldn't that simply keep rewriting the 'comments' variable over and over again with the new set of comments until you get to the last post in newpost_set.all() and your 'comments' variable just takes the value of the set of comments of the very last post on that page.

Comment: Actually, this did work. I just had to make sure to save the entire queryset as is and properly configure the template to display each postcomment in the correct location. You don't even need a for loop for this it turns out. You can simply do the second line as it saves the entire queryset of comments. Thanks for your help!